Can the surreal numbers index the class of automorphisms of the surreal numbers?
For the surreals $\mathbb{S}$ and $z$ any surreal number, can we index every possible $F:\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S}$ by $F_z$?
This would be unlike any other object I've encountered, the set of naturals and the class of ordinals can't do this.
I understand that the surreals can index some large categories like the category of sets, just like an ordinal can index some small categories like the simplex category.
I use the definition that every surreal $z$ can be expressed as an ordered list of 1's and 0's indexed by some ordinal $\omega$.
I presume that the surreals can index their own category since for each $z$, there is a $z^\dagger$ such that every $z'<z$ is contained in $z^\dagger$ to track objects, and there is a $z^{\dagger\prime}$ which contains $z^\dagger$ and a $1$ for every $z''<z^{\dagger\prime}$ to track arrows (this is verifiable by appealing to the initial and terminal objects of each $z'$,$z''$ which are indexed by ordinals). You would run out of natural $z$'s via cardinality, and ordinal $z$'s can't do this because ordinals don't have a choice between 1 and 0, there is no smaller object to index them in this way (conjecture), the set of binary vectors indexed by a set with cardinality $k$ only has cardinality $2^k$. But I don't think you run out of surreal $z$'s since cardinality doesn't apply to a class formed by the binary vectors indexed by any ordinal. The surreals are larger than the ordinals if Cantor's diagonalization argument still applies.
What I can't wrap my head around is how to express every map $F:\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{S}$ so that I may attempt to track these maps with surreals or develop a diagonal argument. We can't use a set to hold every $(z,F(z))$, and I don't know how to form a diagonal argument without appealing to membership in a set.
These automorphisms do form a group $G$ (with a proper class of elements), and the generators of $G$ also form a proper class. If the generators of $G$ can be indexed by ordinals, then the whole group can be indexed by the surreals. The generators are trivially indexed by surreals (just as the generators of the real bijections are the reals), but I don't know that they can't also be indexed by the smaller ordinals; perhaps the generators of G are smaller than the surreals. I'm not sure that if the generators can be indexed by surreals, then the whole group can be indexed by surreals, but I suspect that this is the case.

I’m not very familiar with the surreal numbers, so I may be wrong. But this seems unlikely, given that the surreal numbers, being maximal among all ordered fields, should be saturated and therefore its automorphism group should have strictly larger cardinality. Of course this means we need to be able to talk about “larger” proper classes whose elements are proper classes, but that’s a requirement for this question to make sense in the first place.

Just to avoid any issues, assume there exists an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ and the surreals we’re talking about is constructed within the universe $V_\kappa$. Then the surreals should have cardinality $\kappa$ but its automorphism group should have cardinality $2^\kappa$.

I don't think we can appeal to $\kappa$ in this way here because there would also be limit ordinals $\omega_\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$, $2^\kappa$, etc. and thus surreal numbers indexed by every $\omega_\kappa$

But if surreals are only indexed by accessible ordinals, and an inaccessible cardinal can index the surreals, then your argument makes the result trivial for sure

What I meant is that the entire question runs into lots of issues with foundation, because the surreals form a proper class. So any automorphism of surreals is also a proper class. Thus, the automorphism group of surreals is a collection of proper classes, which cannot just be a proper class but has to be a “larger” or “higher-level” proper class. You have to find a set theory to support that in the first place. Even if that’s done, the issue still remains that you want to ask whether there exists a bijection between surreals and its automorphism group…

… that is by itself a problem, because you’re now asking whether there exists a function from a proper class to a “higher-level” proper class. If you use the usual Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs, such a function can only exists a few levels higher than even the “higher-level” proper class (after all, it will have proper classes as its element’s element’s element.) So you will need a set theory to support that, which is a huge issue…

… What I’m suggesting is to use ZFC + “There exists an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$” as the foundational set theory in which to discuss your problem. And by definition consider only elements of $V_\kappa$ as sets and insist that surreals refer to the maximal ordered field whose elements are all “sets” - so the surreals constructed by pretending $V_\kappa$ is the entire universe, instead of the full proper class $\mathbf{V}$. This allows you to easily discuss the automorphism group and functions between them - they are still elements of $\mathbf{V}$…

… just not “sets” in the above more restrictive sense. Under this sense, you can also talk about the cardinality of surreals and its automorphism group, ending up with $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa$, respectively. So there’s no bijection as desired. Of course, this question might as well have a different answer using a different foundation, but at the very least the above shows it can have a negative answer under some method of formalizing it.

$V_\kappa$ is still a limit ordinal so this doesn't really suit the definition I'm using of surreals being binary ordered lists indexed by ordinals. The extra detail is appreciated, and indeed I am recognizing the foundational limits of this question better with your input. But a fundamental notion here in my question is that the surreals can't be indexed by a set, inaccessible or otherwise. I'm wondering how to study the automorphisms of this without appealing to set theory at all. Indentifying a set which can index the surreals reduces the question to triviality, as I mentioned above.

For clarity, I'm using the definition a class $A$ indexes another class $B$ if there is an epimorphism $f:A \to B$ in the category of classes

It is my understanding that one of the usual choices for the foundation when working with category theory and when “extra large” categories are needed (like the category of classes, which necessarily involves “higher-level” proper classes) is by assuming the existence of plenty of inaccessible cardinals, for example by assuming Tarski’s axiom (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory), then restricting what “sets” mean, as in my comments above. I don’t really see any other way to even formalize the concept of category of classes without something like this…

… and moreover the automorphism group of the surreals is not just a proper class. It is a “higher-level” proper class consisting of functions between proper classes. So this makes it even worse. However, I’m neither a set theorist nor a category theorist, so perhaps someone more familiar with those fields can propose some other way to formalize this question. In that case I wouldn’t be surprised if the answer depends on the choice of formalization.

Perhaps you can consider posting this question, with some added clarification and focus on foundational issues, to MathOverflow. There’s a better chance that someone more familiar with foundational issues will be there and can perhaps shed more light on this.

Thanks, David. I see your issues with the question, and I share the sense that it is somewhat unfounded. I will try the other forum as well.
